# Start service with crontab linux

Tags: scripting, cron

I'm trying to create a shell to start a service, or have it be run by cron every time:

```
00 06 * * * sh /root/teste.sh
```

In the teste.sh file or in the following command:

```
service tomcat start
```

I've also tried with:

```
/usr/sbin/service tomcat_web start
```

Neither way worked. Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? In the cron logs there is no error. It executes, but I do not know if it is correct or not.

Comment: Please enter your question(s) in English.

Comment: Sorry. Help-me?

Comment: I translated it with the help of Google Translate; I mainly wanted to alert you that this site works in English.

Comment: What OS (distribution and version) are you on? If your system uses `systemd`, there's likely no good reason to be starting services from cron. What is the end goal that you're trying to achieve? Do you perhaps just want to respawn a service that dies once in a while?

Comment: Exactly. A service that is falling at times. We are looking to discover the root cause. I provisionally need to make this cron work and get the service up.

Operating System: 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"

Linux 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 # 1 SMP Mon Jul 29 17:46:05 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU / Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out.

Test.sh adjusted file:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROGRAM_START="/orabin01/tomcat/bin/startup.sh"
DAEMON_USER="tomcat"

/bin/su $DAEMON_USER -c "$PROGRAM_START"
```